# How do I add images into interface builder in XCode?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I dragged five images into my supporting files folder.

I tried to drag and drop them from my file panel into the interface builder, but XCode would not let me do so. Do I need to perform an action with something called an "UIImageView"?

How do I add images into interface builder? Thank you, this is my first time programming in XCode.

Comment: You have to bring them into the App bundle by dragging them into your project first.

Comment: Thanks, I think I did drag the images from my Desktop to my supporting files folder though.

Comment: Okay, then you're going to need a UIImageView, which is what the answers are saying...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you drag and drop the images from the "Media Library" section of the Utilities panel directly onto your view, they will automatically create the `UIImageView` and allow you to drop them directly in as illustrated below.

[image]

Comment: Any image added to the project will appear in the media library.

Comment: Also want to make sure you make relative to project.

Comment: @MizAkita: Where?

Comment: @moonman239 drag your images into the root of your project folder or into your xassets folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can select your `UIImageView` in Interface Builder, and then open the attributes inspector, to do so in XCode you will see 3 types of views select the one that opens the panel to the right, then it is the one that looks kinda like a shield, expand Image View, and you can select your image in the drop down box for "Image".

Comment: Where is this? I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you drag and drop plain images into IB. To display images you need a UIImageView object. That's what you will find in Interface Builder. Just drag and drop a UIImageView into the view of controller. UIImageView has image property.From the drop down list of that property you will find the images you added to your project group.Pick any image and that's it. Do not forget that UIImageView can hold only one image in its image property. It's not an NSArray of images. So in case you want to kinda"import" all the images, you'll have to add that many image views to your view.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard for me.
You just first get the image into Xcode and then open interface builder. Then find the image well object in the library and drag it into the window to where you want it to be. Finally just type in the name of the image WITHOUT EXTENSION into the image text box on the right side in image view.